# How do I Trigger the button of other website

Tags: javascript

I have a I frame and inside the iframe is another website.
I want to trigger the button of login to my external button

[image]

Comment: If this iframe is on another domain, then this is XSS. For security, you can't do that, read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Answer (score 3):

If it's from another site/domain, you can't do it, it has to be on the same domain. To access elements within the iframe on the same domain you could use the [frames property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames) of the window object

```
let iframeBtn = window.frames['yourIFrame'].document.getElementById('buttonId');

//code to trigger the button inside the iframe
```

Comment: How to use this for iframe of other domain?

Comment: This is XSS. For security, you can't do that, read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: @Jonathan then this answer will not solve the problem of above question

Comment: You are correct Kiran, thank you for pointing it out, I should have disclosed this from the beginning.

Comment: Give me some tips how to do that in different ways

Comment: It is possible to get the function of that button and add to my external button ?